# Scraping: can't get stable results

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

I'm doing a scraping exercise on a job searching webpage. I want to get the link, name of the company, job title, salary, location and posting date. I've run the same code multiple times, and sometimes it gives the expected results in the salary item (salary if the info is displayed, "N/A" otherwise) and sometimes it gives me something different: salary if the info is displayed, "N/A", and some random character values in columns whose values should be "N/A". I have no problems with the other elements. Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('https://ca.indeed.com/')

#Inputs a job title and location into the input boxes
input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="text-input-what"]')
input_box.send_keys('data analyst')

location = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="text-input-where"]')
location.send_keys('toronto')

#Clicks on the search button
button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="jobsearch"]/button').click()

#Creates a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Link':[''], 'Job Title':[''], 'Company':[''], 'Location':[''],'Salary':[''], 'Date':['']})

#This loop goes through every page and grabs all the details of each posting
#Loop will only end when there are no more pages to go through
while True:  

    #Imports the HTML of the current page into python
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

    #Grabs the HTML of each posting
    postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'slider_container css-g7s71f eu4oa1w0')
    len(postings)

    #grabs all the details for each posting and adds it as a row to the dataframe

    for post in postings:
        link = post.find('a').get('href')
        link_full = 'https://ca.indeed.com'+link
        name = post.find('h2', tabindex = '-1').text.strip()
        company = post.find('span', class_ = 'companyName').text.strip()
        try:
            location = post.find('div', class_ = 'companyLocation').text.strip()
        except:
            location = 'N/A'
        try:
            salary = post.find('div', attrs = {'class':'heading6 tapItem-gutter metadataContainer noJEMChips salaryOnly'}).text.strip()           
        except:
            salary = 'N/A'
        date = post.find('span', class_ = 'date').text.strip()
        df = df.append({'Link':link_full, 'Job Title':name, 'Company':company, 'Location':location,'Salary':salary, 'Date':date},
                       ignore_index = True)
        
    #checks if there is a button to go to the next page, and if not will stop the loop
    try:
        button = soup.find('a', attrs = {'aria-label': 'Next'}).get('href')
        driver.get('https://ca.indeed.com'+button)
    except:
        break
```

Can I fix my code to get the expected results everytime I run it? Also, an additional issue: I'm scraping around 60 pages. But usually the program stops between 20 and 30 pages before the last page. Is there a way to fix the code so that it scrapes until the last page everytime?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Selenium rather than http client lirbary like `requests` or `httpx`? Complexity from a whole browser definitely makes your scraper less stable. For example, your code might break if the next button loads slowly (you should try waiting for the button to appear rather than checking for it instantly on page load).

Comment: @Granitosaurus, I'm doing it that way because I'm still learning the basics, so I just don't know how to do it differently. Also, thanks for your answer: I just added a waiting button and now the code scrapes every page.

Comment: You should make use of `WebDriverWait` (that you already imported) to wait for specific elements showing up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified example with requests library:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cookies = {}
headers = {}
params = {
    'q': 'data analyst',
    'l': 'toronto',
    'from': 'searchOnHP',
}

response = requests.get('https://ca.indeed.com/jobs', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)
postings = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'slider_container css-g7s71f eu4oa1w0')
len(postings)
```

prints

```
15
```